# Nifi: Route on Attribute processor to wrong processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am testing a flow in NIFI that checks for specific value of a counter using REST API. I am able to extract it correct value from REST response. However, when I check the condition in Route on Attribute processor, the expected matched condition's results are routing to unmatched processor.

Attached is the :
[Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jikq6.png) and [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8cZN.png)

I have already checked my response to be "1". But its routing to unmatched branch. 
Is there something wrong with NIFI expression language I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasim,

Initial setup check counter attribute in which value is 1.

And modify the expression language like `${counter:equals('1')} or ${counter:matches('1')}` instead of contains.

because contains not suitable for your scanerio.

Hope this helpful for you.

Comment: don't forget to accept this to be answer if it worked.